# I need to update the record without adding the record in the database

Tags: java, struts

package com.groups.ims.customers.action;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.groups.GroupsCustomSQLException;
import com.groups.GroupsCustomeException;
import com.groups.GroupsFormUtil;
import com.groups.ims.customers.dao.CustomerAddress;
import com.groups.ims.customers.dao.CustomerService;
import com.groups.ims.customers.form.CustomersForm;

public class ViewCustomersAddressDetailsAction extends CustomersAction
{
    @Autowired
    CustomerService customerService;

    public ActionForward executeHibernateAction()
            throws GroupsCustomeException, GroupsCustomSQLException, Exception
    {
        CustomersForm customersForm = (CustomersForm) form;
        HashMap bean = null;

        String customerSeq = customersForm.getSelectedId();
        System.out.println("\n customerSeq : " +customerSeq); 
        customerSeq = nullToEmptyString(customerSeq);

        if (customerSeq.length() == 0)
            throw new GroupsCustomeException("error.details.no.record");

        CustomerAddress bl = customerService.getCustomerAddress(customerSeq);


        List<GroupsFormUtil> props = new ArrayList<GroupsFormUtil>();

        props.add(new GroupsFormUtil("addressName", "addressName"));
        props.add(new GroupsFormUtil("address1", "address1"));

        props.add(new GroupsFormUtil("address2", "address2"));
        props.add(new GroupsFormUtil("address3", "address3"));
        props.add(new GroupsFormUtil("citySeq", "citySeq"));
        props.add(new GroupsFormUtil("stateSeq", "stateSeq"));
        props.add(new GroupsFormUtil("pincode", "pincode"));

        beanToForm(customersForm, bl, props);

         setDetailsSelectBoxLists(session, connection);

        if (customersForm.getTabIDHtml().length() == 0)
        {
            customersForm.setTabIDHtml("customer_address");
        }

        session.setAttribute("CustomersForm", customersForm);

        return mapping.findForward("viewDetails");
    }
}
```

And this is the submit of details action

```
 package com.groups.ims.customers.action;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.groups.GroupsCustomSQLException;
import com.groups.GroupsCustomeException;
import com.groups.GroupsFormUtil;
import com.groups.form.BeanValueFormatter;
import com.groups.form.DateValueFormatterImpl;
import com.groups.form.DateValueFormatterImpl.DATE_TYPE;
import com.groups.form.NumberValueFormatterImpl;
import com.groups.form.NumberValueFormatterImpl.NUMBER_TYPE;
import com.groups.ims.customers.dao.Customer;
import com.groups.ims.customers.dao.CustomerAddress;
import com.groups.ims.customers.dao.CustomerService;
import com.groups.ims.customers.dao.CustomerServiceImpl;
import com.groups.ims.customers.form.CustomersForm;

public class CustomersAddressDetailsSubmitAction extends CustomersAction
{
    @Autowired
    CustomerService customerService;

    public ActionForward executeHibernateAction()
            throws GroupsCustomeException, GroupsCustomSQLException, Exception
    {
        CustomersForm customersForm = (CustomersForm) form;
        customerSeq = customersForm.getSelectedId();

        CustomerAddress bl = customerService.getCustomerAddress(customerSeq);

        List<GroupsFormUtil> props = new ArrayList<GroupsFormUtil>();
        props.add(new GroupsFormUtil("addressName", "addressName"));
        props.add(new GroupsFormUtil("address1", "address1"));
        props.add(new GroupsFormUtil("address2", "address2"));
        props.add(new GroupsFormUtil("address3", "address3"));
        props.add(new GroupsFormUtil("citySeq", "citySeq"));
        props.add(new GroupsFormUtil("stateSeq", "stateSeq"));
        props.add(new GroupsFormUtil("pincode", "pincode"));

        formToBean(customersForm, bl, props);

        bl.updateCustomerAddress(userName,customerSeq);

        return mapping.findForward("viewDetails");
    }
}
```

i just  want to update the record without adding any record in the database

i mean instead of adding the record i want  to update the null record

```
public void updateCustomerAddress(String user, String customerSeq) throws SQLException {
    HashMap bean = new HashMap();

    bean.put("cust_address_name", getAddressName());
    bean.put("cust_address1", getAddress1());
    bean.put("cust_address2", getAddress2());
    bean.put("cust_address3", getAddress3());
    bean.put("cust_city", getCitySeq());
    bean.put("cust_state", getStateSeq());
    bean.put("cust_pincode", getPincode());

    bean.put(GroupsBaseAccess.TABLE_NAME, "customer_address");
    bean.put("update_user", user);
    bean.put("update_date", "now()");
    bean.put("where", "customer_seq=" + customerSeq);

    GroupsBaseAccess.update(bean, getConnection());
}
```

The query is:

```
String customerAddressQuery = "(select    cust_addr_seq, cust_address_name, cust_address1, cust_address2, cust_address3, cust_city, cust_state, cust_pincode" +
                              " from customer_address where <customer_seq> )";
```

Comment: You omitted to post the **relevant** code: The DB - Queries ...

Comment: 1. Load the database object using id and update the values. So it will update the existing record.